# Question about Arabic language

Tags: discussion, arabic

I have asked [What does mean "may your hand be besmeared with dust"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/what-does-mean-may-your-hand-be-besmeared-with-dust) about Arabic language, but it is also about translation, meaning of hadiths.

I want post it also in http://arabic.stackexchange.com/ with little changes (Arabic idiom in title).

Then seems there is a problem of 2 places where answers can be written. I think it is not very bad because I will provide links from each to other and people can write answer only once in that site for which it is more appropriate.

I think I will ask them to post their answer to only one of the sites.

What do you recommend?

Comment: already asked in arabic stackexchange : http://arabic.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-do-we-translate-%D8%AA%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%90%D8%A8%D9%8E%D8%AA%D9%92-%D9%8A%D9%8E%D8%AF%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%83%D9%8E-to-english

Comment: Would it be possible to get the answer of your question somehow?

Comment: @MediSaif i do not understand you. which question? ok i think somebody may answer it .

Comment: Well i guess your Question has been answered in Arabic SE it would be helpful if you could provide the answer in the Question here on islam SE

Comment: that link does not work, arabic se is closed. maybe i will copy answer to islam se

Comment: i know that's why i asked, because it was as far as i recall an enlightening answer to me too! So i would appreciate if you could post it!

Comment: i have not found its copies...

Comment: it is possible to download it from the area51 page, where deleted site redirects, you can see link to download. the question has PostId="86", and answers have 88 and 89, and also their revisions. i have wanted to copy that answers, but this time i see they do not answer well to my question.

Comment: see what i have decoded (there were html entities) : http://qdb.tmf.org.ru/fayllar/tarbit.html